# How to have UIButton image using UIButton.Configuration adapt and resize dynamically to the button size

Tags: swift, uikit, uibutton

I would like to use UIButton.Configuration to create and configure UIKit buttons in the app.

I cannot have the image in the button resizing accordingly to the size of the button itself leading to an image that expands outside of the button bounds.

Before configuration I was using `.scaleAspectFit` on the button `imageView` `contentMode` property.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let button1 = {
        let filterImageUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filter@2x", withExtension: "png")!
        let filterImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filterImageUrl.absoluteURL.path)

        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        configuration.image = filterImage
        configuration.imagePadding = 5
        configuration.cornerStyle = .medium
        configuration.baseBackgroundColor = .darkGray
        configuration.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)


        let button = UIButton(configuration: configuration)
        button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return button
    }()

    let button2 = {
        var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
        configuration.image = UIImage(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle")
        configuration.imagePadding = 5
        configuration.cornerStyle = .medium
        configuration.baseBackgroundColor = .darkGray

        let button = UIButton(configuration: configuration)
        button.setPreferredSymbolConfiguration(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: UIImage.SymbolScale.small), forImageIn: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(button1)
        self.view.addSubview(button2)

        let constraint = [
            button1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            button1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            button1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            button1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            button2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button1.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            button2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            button2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            button2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraint)
    }
}
```

The result is

---

### [image: Images in the buttons expands outside them]

I tried to play with constraints, including `imageView` constraints against enclosing UIButton.

Also explored UIImage.Configuration

I also expects `contentInsets` configuration to force the image to resize inside the button

Comment: Unclear what the goal is (and how the goal differs from your screenshot, which looks fine to me). Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you @matt for your feedbacks. I'm not very used to ask questions.
As you can see in the screenshot, the image inside the button doesn't scale to fit inside it following nor the `imagePadding`, neither the `contentInsets` directives of the `UIButton.Configuration`.
As I mentioned, I would like `contentInsets` configuration to *force* the image to resize inside the button.
I updated the screenshot to have it more clear.

Comment: Okay, so point one, you have not understood what `imagePadding` is. It is about the space _between_ the image and the title. But there is no title so it is irrelevant. But maybe you were just playing around in desperation. :)

Comment: You're right 'desperation' is a good term. Actually I was more focus on `contentInsets`. I wrongly thought that it will force all contents (including the image) to shrink.

Before using `UIButton.Configuration`, `.scaleAspectFit` did the job.

I use now Configuration to use `contentInsets` since `contentEdgeInsets` has been deprecated in iOS 15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right that the image is not resized to fit the button; it's the other way around. Let the image, plus the configuration's `contentInsets`, size the button for you. Here's an example (from `viewDidLoad`) based loosely on your code:

```
let button = {
    var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.filled()
    configuration.image = UIImage(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle")!
        .applyingSymbolConfiguration(.init(pointSize: 100))
    configuration.cornerStyle = .medium
    configuration.baseBackgroundColor = .darkGray
    configuration.contentInsets = .zero
    let button = UIButton(configuration: configuration)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return button
}()

self.view.addSubview(button)

let constraints = [
    button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
]

NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

To vary the amount of "border" (padding? margin?), change the `contentInsets` value.

Comment: Thank you.
Using `.applyingSymbolConfiguration(.init(pointSize: 100))` and playing with the `pointSize` parameter I can achieve my goal.
But it only works for symbol images ... how to have similar behavior with custom and/or asset images ?

Comment: You would simply redraw the image at the desired size. That's easy but it is not what you asked, and how to do it has been explained here many times. The point is simply to start with the right sized image rather than expecting the button to resize it for you.

Comment: Thank you (again). 
It's a bit disappointing in terms of API as we would like to fix the size of the button and let the image scale accordingly. It was possible with legacy API and you lead me to what I read: have a appropriate image at first or resize it before adding it to the image.

Answer (score -1):

For me the following has worked

```
self.configuration?.image = yourImage.resizedToFit(in: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
```

You can now use the resized image. Unfortunately I didn't find any other way to do so for UIImage except this one.

Comment: I looks like you have an extension of `UIImage` 